# Import .sql file in Access

Tags: sql, mysql, ms-access

I need to import to Access a .sql database backup file created with MySql .

Is there a way to perform this operation?

Comment: How do you mean? What does the .sql file contain?

Comment: This file contain a Mysql Database backup.

Comment: @user555102: in the Access file, is the table(s) you're importing into actually linked tables from a MySQL server?  Or is it just a local Access table?

Comment: @user555102: also, do you have remote access to the MySQL server where you could just link to the remote Mysql tables from within your Access file (via odbc)?

Answer (score 3):

You can't restore a MySQL backup into any other database system.

If you want to import the MySQL data into Access, you could export it all into CSV files and import those to Access. You will still need to recreate relationships, defaults, indexes (?) and other data.

Comment: Yes that's seems a good way but i don't know how i can export these data in csv format

Comment: @user555102 - A quick google found this, amongst many many many results: http://ariejan.net/2008/11/27/export-csv-directly-from-mysql/

Answer (score -1):

You can import SQL Server data into a new Access table. In general, importing is a way to convert data from a different format and copy it into Access. The source table or file is not altered in this process. You can import directly from a SQL Server database using an ODBC connection, a text file exported from SQL Server, or an XML file exported from SQL Server.

To make frequent import operations more convenient, you can automate them by creating a macro or creating a Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) procedure. This is useful, for example, when you import data on a regular schedule or you have unusual or complex requirements for importing data.

Comment: He is using MySql, not SQL Server. Read the question.

Comment: He's talking about MySQL - not Microsoft SQL Server.

Answer (score -2):

if you use SQL Server Management studio then you can open the .SQL files and it will give you help in figuring out what syntax works in SQL -- and which doesn't.

For example, if you have a table name that is mis-spelled, SQL Server Management Studio will give you red squigglies under that table name.

I don't see that functionality in Access, and I don't think that it's coming any time soon. Access (Jet) hasn't gotten any new features in almost fifteen years.

Comment: This has nothing to do with importing sql data into microsoft access. How is that helpful to a question about how to import sql data into access?